# Find extension for distribution defined on $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

> Let $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}) := C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}), f(x) := \frac{1}{\lvert x \vert^n}$ and consider the function $$T_f : \mathcal D(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}) \to \mathbb C; \quad \phi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\phi(x)}{\lvert x \rvert^n} \, dx.$$
>   Find an explicit distribution $T\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $T\restriction_{\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\})} = T_f$.

I first tried to do it when $n=1$ for simplicity. But even then I had no good idea how to start. My idea was to use integration by parts or Taylor to "weaken the singularity" and make the integral well-defined for all test functions, not necessarily vanishing at $0$, but I could not quite get that to work. I believe the solution should be something involing a delta distribution at $0$. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Let $\langle S,\phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0) e^{-|x|^2}}{\lvert x \rvert^n} \, dx$ then $S-T$ is a distribution supported at $0$ thus it is a finite sum of $\delta^{(\alpha)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the distribution $T$ defined by
\begin{align*}
T(\phi)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1/N\leq|x|\leq 1}\dfrac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|^{n}}dx+\int_{|x|\geq 1}\dfrac{\phi(x)}{|x|^{n}}dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is nice. The left integral is well defined and can be estimated by $C \lVert \nabla \varphi \rVert_\infty$ and hence $T$ is a distribution which coincides with $T_f$ for test functions vanishing at $0$. Can this be generalized to higher (e.g. $\lvert x \rvert^{-n-1})$ singularities at the origin?

Comment: The dimension $n$ is exact, as you can see from the theory of singular integrals, I think counterexamples are ready for higher index.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(0)=0$ and for $x \neq 0$,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2-n} |x|^{2-n} \ln|x| & (n\neq 2) \\
\frac{1}{2}(\ln |x|)^2 & (n=2)
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and therefore defines a distribution $u$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, $\Delta f(x) = |x|^{-n}$ for $x \neq 0$.

Thus we can take $T = \Delta u$.